# How to dynamically fill a state based on textfield input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that is rendered using a JavaScript object called model and a  text-field that takes in an input. Based on this the state needs to be updated.

Unfortunately the state is updated to the last entry input. And not all the values in the form that have been filled in.

I haven't managed to get the methods mentioned here to work for me: [How to fill a specific state with a dynamic key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406355/how-to-fill-a-specific-state-with-a-dynamic-key)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
       Form:{},
    }
}

 onChange = (e, key, type) => {

    let list = [];

    if (type === "text") {
      list[key] =  e.target.value;
    } 

    else {
      // LOGIC TO HANDLE NON TEXT VALUES
      let found = this.state.Form[key]? true : false;
      if (found) {  
        list[key] = false;
        } else {
          list[key]= true;
        }
    }

    this.setState({ Form: list });

  };

renderform = () => {
  return model.map(m => {

     <TextField
          type={m.type}
          key={m.key}
          onChange={event => { this.onChange(event, m.key, "text"); }}
        />

  })
}
```

Comment: this is an array `Form:[]` but you are treating it like an object

Comment: What is `m.key`, `model`?

Comment: m.key is the key of the object i.e: Apple:true   - where 'Apple' is the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ Form: {...prevState.Form, ...list} }));
```

because when you use `this.setState({ Form: list });` your `Form` state is overwritten with a new array everytime.

Comment: im sorry this gives me this error:   Line 190:48:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Comment: @Aims.kar - Updated my answer. And also make sure that the logic inside `onChange` is correct.

Comment: This code previously worked with nothing in the state with updates being something like this.setState{ [key]:false}  - The main issue is now that its a specific state that needs updating  -  its now throwing an error prevState.FilledForm is not iterable  - the form state needs to be empty and built on as the form is filled - so it can't iterate through an empty state - I do not understand how to fix this?

Comment: @Aims.kar - As someone mentioned in the comments you're using the array as an object.  Try changing  `let list = [];` to `let list = {}`. Although that alone may not fix the issue. I would suggest creating a stackblitz of this. Also updated my answer again.